# SQL subtract times from tables (decreased additionally for specific time status from second table)

Tags: sql, subtraction

I have table T1 and T2.

T1

```
ID    TIME1    TIME2  
1001    1        10
1002    1        20
```

T2

```
ID        STATUS    TIME
1001      NEW         1
1001      CLOSED      10
1002      NEW         1
1002      HOLD        5
1002      CLOSED      13
```

I want result TIME2-TIME1 if status HOLD does not exist in table T2; or TIME2-TIME1-TIME if status HOLD exist in table for that record

```
1001   9 (10-1)
1002   14(20-1-5)
```

I initially wrote SQL query but this does not work because it returns NULL for first record while the for the second record result  is OK

```
SELECT T1.ID,T1.TIME2-T1.TIME1-T2.TIME
FROM T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN T2 ON T1.ID=T2.ID AND T2.STATUS='HOLD'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or in short

```
select 
    t1.id,
    t1.time2-case when status='HOLD' then t2.time else 0 end-t1.time1
from
    t1 left join t2 on t1.id=t2.id and t2.status='HOLD'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT T1.ID
    , Case 
            When T2.STATUS = 'HOLD' THEN T1.Time2 - T1.Time1 - T2.Time 
            Else T1.Time2 -T1.Time1 
      END
FROM T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN T2 ON T1.ID=T2.ID AND T2.STATUS='HOLD'
```

Answer (score 1):

Evidently table T2 may contain *more than one row* matching T1.ID.  Assuming that T2 always contains *at least* one such row, then we can do:

```
select T1.ID, min(case when T2.STATUS<>'HOLD' then T1.TIME2-T1.TIME1 
when T2.STATUS='HOLD' then  T1.TIME2-T1.TIME1-T2.[TIME] end)
from T1   join  T2 
on T1.ID=T2.ID
group by T1.ID
```

Comment: The sample data suggest that T2 will always contain some row for T1.ID, and if so I think your `min(case...)` approach works.  However then the `left outer join` is then unnecessary.  If a matching row of T2 is missing, the `left outer join` gives only null values of T2.STATUS to operate on, and the case logic fails.

Comment: @hardmath: Thanks for your comment, I have replaced left outer join with simple join